# Is there a theory to diagonalize the following Hamiltonian?

Tags: operators, hamiltonian, unitarity

I've been trying to find a unitary operator that diagonalizes the following Hamiltonian:

$$\hat H=\hat a^{\dagger}\hat a(\hat b^{\dagger}+\hat b)+ \hat b^{\dagger}\hat b(\hat a^{\dagger}+\hat a)$$

where $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ are usual photon and phonon bosonic operators respectively.

I have tried many unitaries of different forms but have not been able to find one. I am rather new to this subject so I don't know whether there is a general theory to find the diagonalization or not.

Since the above Hamiltonian is Hermitian, I think it should be diagonalizable. Can someone provide an approach I could follow for this problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128340/discussion-on-question-by-lost-is-there-a-theory-to-diagonalize-the-following-ha).